# mod_rewrite do not change links when rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following to my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

When I call www.mydomain.com/page/myvalue I get the correct result. In order to to that though I'll need to change all links to my website correct?

Is there a way to accomplish the opposite i.e. when I call index.php?page=$1 to redirect me to www.mydomain.com/page/myvalue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks it seems it works by adding the full path eg RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com/page/%1? [R=301,L] but all links (css, images etc) must be called with absolute path. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It is always best practice to call css, js, images with absolute path however you can take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_href.asp as well.

Comment: Thanks again soved. A last question please. How can I add two values? i.e. cat=first&page=second?

Comment: Write it like this: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)&page=([^\s&]+) [NC]`

Comment: Thanks, I figured that part out its the rule that I do not manage to write RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com/page/%1? [R=301,L]

Comment: You can write: `RewriteRule ^ /cat/%1/page/%2? [R=301,L]`